# Map Location names in drop down list

Tags: ios, mapkit

My App Has to integrate search location names using text box. Is Map kit has any method to implement this kind of a functionality ? This below image displays what i exactly need

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** , there is not any method of MapKit to implement this type of property..

For That You have to implement Your own Code, i.e. use of UISearchbarCantroller or Simple UISearchbar.

For Search results you can use  [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) api.

You can Use this [GooglePlacesAutocomplete Example](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete).

In 
iOS >= 6.1 provides [MKLocalSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete), [MKLocalSearchRequest](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete) to search for natural language points of interest. Sample

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = regionToSearchIn;
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurants"; // or business name
MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // do something with the results / error
}];
```