# How to search for locations using UISearchBar with autocompletion and suggestions?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, uisearchbar, mklocalsearch

I am developing an app in which user can search for a point of interests, pick a search result and then the MKMapView will be centered to the result coordinate.

My question is how to make autocompletion happen? I have did research on  `MKLocalSearch` and `MKLocalSearchRequest`, and it seems that is Apple suggested API for location search on iOS6.1+. However I cannot find any examples with autocompletion or suggestions with `MKLocalSearch` and `MKLocalSearchRequest`. Is it possible to autocomplete a location search or display a list of suggestions just like Apple's Maps app? Thanks!

Comment: if you like to add the Google location means then there is an free API for location Search like the following http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true and also you can list them out in a UITableView and when user click's an cell you can dynamically add it into the SearchBox.

Answer (score 7):

Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141677/1464327

Basically, you can make multiple requests. For exemple, when the user types, start a timer, when the timer finishes, make a request. Whenever the user types, cancel the previous timer.

Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` of the text field delegate.

```
static NSTimer *_timer = nil;
[_timer invalidate];
_timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(_search:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then implement the _search method to make the request.

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = regionToSearchIn;
request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.textField.text;
MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // check for error and process the response
}];
```

I've never implemented something like this. I'm just telling what my starting point would be. Hopefully this will give you some direction.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` than `NSTimer`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7061472/242933

Comment: Just FYI for anyone else, UISearchBarDelegate has it's own method for [`searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624328-searchbar?language=objc).